# Unable to click the dropdown button

Tags: python-2.7, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I am trying to click the drop-down element.

My HTML:

```html
<select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_ctl28_PageDropDownList" style="width:80px;" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv$ctl28$PageDropDownList\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv$ctl28$PageDropDownList">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

Note: Unable to click the "__doPostBack" using scrapy/python.

Comment: Not enough information, could you share the link to the web-site where we can see the dropdown? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try this

[FormRequest.from_response()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest)

use the **submit** button's name/id as the value for **"__EVENTTARGET"** in the formdata.